# Content View in UITableViewCell not getting updated when changed from one section to another

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, reloaddata

I have used a UITableView to display two different lists as sections in my project. The table view looks like the following:

- Section1 Header
- Apple -
- Kiwi  -
- Mango -
- Section2 Header
- Orange +
- Red    +
- Blue   +

Each cell's contentView contains a UILabel and UIButton(- or +), I used separate arrays for both sections. If Button is clicked(either - or +) I have to move the item from one section to another , I have done this by removing items from one array and adding to another and reloading the table. Below is my current state of code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
            if (cell == nil)
            {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
                [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
                cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

            }
            cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
            UILabel* label = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1234];
                        UIButton* addOrRemoveButton = (UIButton*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1010];
            [addOrRemoveButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:(0.5 * addOrRemoveButton.frame.size.width)]];


        if (indexPath.section==FRUITS) {


            NSString* fruitName = [self.fruitsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            label.text = fruitName;


            [addOrRemoveButton setTitle:@"-" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            [addOrRemoveButton addTarget:self action:@selector(addOrRemove:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

            return cell;

        }
        if (indexPath.section == COLORS){           

            NSString *colorName = [self.colorsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            label.text = colorName;
            [addOrRemoveButton setTitle:@"+" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [addOrRemoveButton addTarget:self action:@selector(addOrRemove:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];           
            return cell;
        }
```

In addOrRemove function:

```
-(void)addOrRemove:(id)sender
{ 
    CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.LanguageTable];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.LanguageTable indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.LanguageTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIButton *symbolBtn = (UIButton*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1010];

    NSString *selectedItem = [NSString alloc] init];

    if(indexPath.section == FRUITS) {
        if(indexPath.row < self.fruitsArray.count)
        selectedItem = [self.fruitsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else {
        if(indexPath.row < self.colorsArray.count)
        selectedItem = [self.colorsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

   NSMutableArray *tempArray = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];

   if(indexPath.section == FRUITS) {
     tempArray = [self.fruitsArray mutableCopy];
     for(NSString* fruit in self.fruitsArray) {
             if([fruit isEqualToString selectedItem]) {
                   [tempArray removeObject: fruit];
                   [self.colorsArray addObject:fruit];
                 }
             self.fruitsArray = [tempArray mutableCopy];
             [tempArray removeAllObjects];
     }
   else {
     tempArray = [self.colorsArray mutableCopy];
     for(NSString* color in self.colorsArray) {
             if([color isEqualToString selectedItem]) {
                   [tempArray removeObject: color];
                   [self.fruitsArray addObject:fruit];
                 }
             self.colorsArray = [tempArray mutableCopy];
             [tempArray removeAllObjects];
             [self.tableView reloadData];
     }
```

I know the code looks a bit devious, I have also tried straight forward way (i.e.
 by using `indexPath.row` to add and remove item in arrays) , But that is not the issue here , the function works fine , items move from one section to another when reloaded, but the **UIButton's title** remains the same such as below,

- Section1 Header
- Apple **-**
- Kiwi  **-**
- Mango **-**
- Orange **+**
- Section2 Header
- Red    **+**
- Blue   **+**

EDIT:

The table view should actually be appeared like below:

- Section1 Header
- Apple **-**
- Kiwi  **-**
- Mango **-**
- Orange **-**
- Section2 Header
- Red    **+**
- Blue   **+**

I guess the solution will be simple , but I dint find it yet. Is anything missing in my code?

Comment: why dont you create a custom cell and it will make your life very easy.

Comment: @AdeelUrRehman Thank you. Ya, it will be easier, but I need a way to solve this issue without custom cell creation as I have to change in lot of tables with different contents in them.

Comment: "items move from one section to another when reloaded, but the symbol remains the same." What were you expecting it to be?

Comment: @jlehr Please, have a look at edit in question.